# Flutter screen not changing after provider state changed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-3.0

I'm new in flutter and trying to understand flutter state management concept using provider. This the image scenario what I'm trying to do

[image]

I have created a file called auth_provider.dart file under the folder called Providers

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier{
    
    bool isLogin = false;

    Future createUser() async
    {
        isLogin = true; 
        notifyListeners();
    }

    Future login() async
    {
        isLogin = true; 
        notifyListeners();
    }

    void logout()
    {
        isLogin = false; 
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

This the Signup button that I have created in the login page

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const SignupPage()
            ),
        );
    },
    child: const Text(
        'Signup Button',
    ),
)
```

This is the signUp button in signup screen

```
child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => signUpSubmit(),
    child: const Text(
        'Sign Up',
    ),
),
```

I have written a signUpSubmit future like below

```
Future<void> signUpSubmit() async {
    Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).createUser();
}
```

I have used AuthProvider consumer in main.dart page

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
                ),
            ],

            child: Consumer<AuthProvider>(
                builder: (ctx,auth,child){
                    print(auth.isLogin);
                    return MaterialApp(         
                        home: auth.isLogin ? const HomeScreen():const LoginPage(),
            
                        routes: {
                            HomeScreen.routeName: (ctx) => const HomeScreen(),
                            SignupPage.routeName: (ctx) => const SignupPage(),
                            LoginPage.routeName: (ctx) => const LoginPage(),
                        },
                    );
                }      
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

After click on signup button I'm getting true in main page , which I have given a print under Consumer builder in main.dart page. So according to MaterialApp widget home condition page should redirect to HomeScreen but it's not moving. Why it's not moving ? What is the main cause and what it the best way to solve this problem ?

**Note : If I try it from login screen redirection is working fine. But according to my image flow (Login -> signup) it's not working.**

Comment: is the consumer actively listening to the stream of data? I'd suggest using firebase auth for authentication, but it totally depends on your use case.

Comment: There has no any API integration I have build,  function will always return true if I call it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code you are looking for, but bear in mind with the implementation you have right now, if the user opens the app again, it will redirect them to the signin page. because the boolean value will disappear once the user closes the app.

change your main.dart file like the following..

main function

```
void main() {
// you just need to add the multiprovider and the change notifier provider class
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

here is the MyApp class as i understand it.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (ctx, auth, child) {
      print(auth.isLogin);
      return MaterialApp(
        home: auth.isLogin ? MyHomePage() : LoginPage(),
        routes: {
          MyHomePage.routeName: (ctx) => MyHomePage(),
          LoginPage.routeName: (ctx) => LoginPage(),
          //NavScreen.routeName: (ctx) => const NavScreen(),
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Change the signup button in the register page to the following.

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            signUpSubmit(context);
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
          },
```

and the signupsubmit function like this..

```
signUpSubmit(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).createUser();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Danny Provider registration part I already did in builder , I have updated my question. My only question is why it's not redirection after state made true ?

Comment: it is redirecting for me.. i have tried it and it works.. have you set the MultiProvider class in the main function?

Comment: I have set it in Widget build.

Comment: If I try it in login page it's working fine , but if you create a button in login page to go signup page , then try it in signup page it will not work !

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: why I do I need to redirect user by enforced  ? Why condition is not working in MaterialApp widget ?

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of your problem is that you are  pushing a new route (screen) from login page and the best way to solve problem is to pop that route (screen) from sigupPage.

On click of Signup button from login page you are pushing a new route, so in order to redirect to HomeScreen from SignupPage first you need to pop that route so that you can see the updated changes.

```
Future<void> signUpSubmit() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).createUser();
  }
```

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics